# Is there a stable docker image for logstash that will track fixes?

Tags: logstash

Elasticsearch make a list of docker images [available](https://www.docker.elastic.co/r/logstash), but this only contains specific versions.  Is there a way to track the latest stable docker v7 release so that cron-driven rebuilds of my container will keep it on a good patch version?

Comment: In my case, I am using a pooling method that runs cron every weekend.
One shell was registered and used in the cron job. First, in the state that this link file is saved, check if changes occur, change the file, update latest, and execute a shell that reflects it in the docker container.  [logstash/v7/Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/logstash/blob/master/7/Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks @myeongkilkim, but I am looking for a solution that gets the latest stable image without needing me to hardcode the exact version number.